# Cannot parcel a Location

Tags: android, location, parcelable, parcel, fusedlocationproviderclient

Greetings from Germany!

Today I ran into a very strange problem trying to do this:
Location -> Parcel -> Location

I tried to create parcels from a Location with these methods:
    location.writeToParcel(parcel, flags)    and
    parcel.writeParcelable(location, flags)

and to retrieve the location back from these parcels using:
    parcel.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader())    and
    Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)

The following code snipplets show all 4 possible combinations going from a valid location (see top part of the code) to a parcel and back to the location. However, neither way works as expected and I'm running out of ideas what is going wrong here.

The relevant parts of the log are shown in the comments after trying to retrieve the location from the parcels.

I'm starting with a valid location as shown here:

```
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Parcel;
    [...]

    // locationList as arrived in a broadcast via FusedLocationProviderClient, locations are O.K.
    Location location = locationList.get(0);
    Timber.d("in: "+String.format("%.1f",location.getLatitude()) + "/" +
                    String.format("%.1f",(location.getLongitude())));
    //  result: "[...] in: 47,8/12,6" (<- just to demonstrate locations are fine at this point)
```

However, I don't seem to get a valid parcel from this location.

Frist try: creating the parcel with parcel.writeParcelable()

```
    Parcel parcel1 = Parcel.obtain();
    parcel1.writeParcelable(location, 0);

    Location location1a = parcel1.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
    Timber.d("out1a: "+String.format("%.1f",location1a.getLatitude()) + "/" +
                       String.format("%.1f",(location1a.getLongitude())));
    // result: NullPointerException "[...] Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"

    Location location1b = Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel1);
    Timber.d("out1b: "+String.format("%.1f",location1b.getLatitude()) + "/" +
                       String.format("%.1f",(location1b.getLongitude())));
    // result: "[...] out1b: 0,0/0,0"
```

I should add

- parcel1 looks completely unchanged after parcel.writeParcelable() in the debugger
- not only latitude and longitude are 0, but all data within location1b

Second try: creating the parcel with location.writeToParcel()

```
    Parcel parcel2 = Parcel.obtain();
    location.writeToParcel(parcel2, 0);

    Location location2a = parcel1.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
    Timber.d("out2a: "+String.format("%.1f",location2a.getLatitude()) + "/" +
                       String.format("%.1f",(location2a.getLongitude())));
    // result: NullPointerException "... Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"

    Location location2b = Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel2);
    Timber.d("out2b: "+String.format("%.1f",location2b.getLatitude()) + "/" +
                       String.format("%.1f",(location2b.getLongitude())));
    // result: "[...] out2b: 0,0/0,0"
```

And again, all data within location2b are 0 and also parcel2 looks unchanged after location.writeToParcel() to me.

Looks like there is something fundamentally going wrong. Any idea what it is? Did Location forget how to properly save it's state into a parcel over night, or did I forget the correct way how to parcel a location?

(using a real device with Android 7.0)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm now able to answer my own question.

The problem is, that Location never calls
parcel.setDataPosition(0).
In my opinion that should be done in the Location class before reading the parcel:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Location> CREATOR =
    new Parcelable.Creator<Location>() {
    @Override
    public Location createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        in.setDataPosition(0);            // this statement is missing!
        String provider = in.readString();
        Location l = new Location(provider);
        l.mTime = in.readLong();
        l.mElapsedRealtimeNanos = in.readLong();
        l.mFieldsMask = in.readByte();
        l.mLatitude = in.readDouble();
        l.mLongitude = in.readDouble();
        l.mAltitude = in.readDouble();
        l.mSpeed = in.readFloat();
        l.mBearing = in.readFloat();
        l.mHorizontalAccuracyMeters = in.readFloat();
        l.mVerticalAccuracyMeters = in.readFloat();
        l.mSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond = in.readFloat();
        l.mBearingAccuracyDegrees = in.readFloat();
        l.mExtras = Bundle.setDefusable(in.readBundle(), true);
        return l;
    }
```

However, that doesn't happen. The consequence is, that Location gets only nulls from the parcel.

In order to get our location back from the parcel, we need to reset the parcel's data position manually.

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Parcel;

// get a location from somewhere, then obtain the parcel 
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
location.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);    // or: parcel.writeParcelable(location, 0);

// send the parcel somewhere and retrieve the location like this:
parcel.setDataPosition(0);           // must be done before the location can be retrieved!
Location location = Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);    // or: location = parcel.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
```

This way everything works fine.

Thanks for taking your time to look at this issue!

Comment: I don't know how no one else has run into this, but you saved me on this one. Thanks kindly.

Comment: The reason the `setDataPositon(0)` is not in there is because the `Location` could be part of a larger parcel containing other data.

FWIW, my use case for storing the `Parcel` instead of the `Location` itself is that I was having trouble with `Location`s being updated under my feet after I stored them. I'm now storing `Parcel`s containing locations so they can't change.